# pyqtgraph ImageItem missing scale() function?

Tags: python, qt, charts, pyside, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to implement a spectrograph following [This question for guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312923/plotting-the-spectrum-of-a-wavfile-in-pyqtgraph-using-scipy-signal-spectrogram).
However, one of the called function of `ImageItem` seems to be "missing".

In the linked question, there is this line (img is a `ImageItem`):

```py
img.scale(t[-1] / np.size(Sxx, axis=1),
          f[-1] / np.size(Sxx, axis=0))
```

But, when I try to use the same line, I get the error:

```
TypeError: ImageItem.scale() takes no arguments (4 given)
```

Looking at the source, it appears the `scale()` function from Qt's `QGraphicsItem` is being called, which returns the current scale, and printing a call without arguments confirms it, printing `1.0`.

Is there a different function I need to call to set the `ImageItem` scale?

Comment: Almost all Qt object properties use `someProperty()` as getter and `setSomeProperty()` as setter; all pyqtgraph graphics item inherit from Qt [QGraphicsItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html), so [`scale()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#scale) is the *getter*, [`setScale()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setScale) the setter. Note that the scale is the orthogonal ratio (in fact you get only *one* value), meaning that it represents *both* horizontal and vertical scale, and `setScale()` obviously follows the same logic, so even if you change `scale` to `setScale` you'll »

Comment: » still get an error because of the wrong argument count; btw, your call above shouldn't give you that error, since you're providing 3 arguments (the instance is implicit, since it's a method), not 4, so you're posting either a wrong error or the wrong function call. In any case, graphics items don't directly provide means to scale with different x/y ratios. The only way to achieve so is by working with [`setTransformations()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setTransformations), hoping it doesn't mess up things with the internal transforms pyqtgraphs use.

Comment: @musicamante I just realized I had typed the function call wrong, I was giving it 4 arguments, hence the wrong error, the error now says there are 2 arguments. If `scale()` has always been the getter for `QGraphcsItem`, why would the accepted answer of the linked question use it? I also tried doing what the ` [ImageItem](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/graphicsItems/imageitem.html#pyqtgraph.ImageItem) ` does, use a `QTransform`, and scale that, but the scale of the image still doesn't match the plot.

Comment: You're partially right, sorry. QGraphicsItem **used** to provide the `scale(sx, sy)` function as a setter, but it was already considered [obsolete in Qt4](//doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem-obsolete.html#scale-2), still available (but deprecated) [in Qt5](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem-obsolete.html#scale) (probably for compatibility reasons) and no more available since earlier Qt5 versions and Qt6. The linked answer probably used a Qt version that still supported it or a PyQt one built supporting obsolete features. Consider [this solution](//stackoverflow.com/a/39416346) instead.